# no A record show in the answer section in dig results

Tags: domain-name-system

To check the record for the domain, run dig with domain name as the parameter.

dig example.com any

I get the below result. Why there is no A record show in the result. What did i do wrong during the setup. Please advice what suppose to look into it. Hope everyone can help me to resolve the case asap.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-P2 <<>> example.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44674
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.       IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.    3489    IN  MX  100 biz.mail.com.
example.com.    3482    IN  NS  ns1.domain.com.
example.com.    3482    IN  NS  ns2.domain.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.    3482    IN  NS  ns2.domain.com.
example.com.    3482    IN  NS  ns1.domain.com.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: xxx.252.xxx.xxx#53(xxx.252.xxx.xxx)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 30 04:48:34 CDT 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 349
```

Comment: If this is a problem with your DNS server it might be helpful to add your DNS config and the steps you took to put it in place (specifically, did you restart the service after editing the files?) and any errors that might have been logged when you restarted it.

Comment: Q: "Why there is no A record show in the result?" A: "Because you didn't create one."

Answer (score 0):

Is this your domain you are talking about?

It's perfectly normal to have no `A` record for a "naked" domain. In this case, you will need to have hosts like `www.example.com` etc. to have `A` or `CNAME` records. If you want `example.com` to resolve to a host, just add an `A` record for `example.com` into the DNS for this domain.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's difficult to be conclusive about this but unfortunately because of the way Stack Exchange works I can't yet ask for more information in a comment - as a new user, I don't have that privilege yet!

How exactly is your DNS configured? Are you running your own DNS server, or just configuring records on some hosted platform? What does the configuration/zone file look like? You're asking a question without supplying much of the information we need to actually answer it.

Anonymising your domain (changing it to example.com) means we can't make guesses about what's likely to be the case, or examine your DNS servers directly.

That said, assuming you're running your own DNS server based on BIND (or BIND-like zone files), you need a record like this in your zone file:

```
@        IN        A        <ip>
```

or

```
example.com.        IN        A        <ip>
```

Note that in the latter example, the trailing full stop after the domain name is very important - without that, you'll be creating an A record at "example.com.example.com".